# How do I get SQLite to work in my C++ project?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I am trying to use SQLite in my Linux C++ project and I have installed SQLite using `apt-get sqlite3`. Now I need to get SQLite included in my project but I don't know how to do this.

How do I get SQLite to be included in my project?

I'm using CLion, if that helps at all.

Comment: Try looking at https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/5vego1/how_do_i_use_sqlite_with_clion/

Comment: @Alexander: as long as your edits need reviewing, please make them substantial. Bolding and adding unnecessary `code` ticks `to` random stuff does *not* equal making "your post easy to see".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simple C program that demonstrates how to use the C/C++ interface to SQLite. The name of a database is given by the first argument and the second argument is one or more SQL statements to execute against the database. The function calls to pay attention to here are the call to sqlite3_open() on line 22 which opens the database, sqlite3_exec() on line 28 that executes SQL commands against the database, and sqlite3_close() on line 33 that closes the database connection.

```
 01  #include <stdio.h>
 02  #include <sqlite3.h>
 03  
 04  static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
 05    int i;
 06    for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
 07      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
 08    }
 09    printf("\n");
 10    return 0;
 11  }
 12  
 13  int main(int argc, char **argv){
 14    sqlite3 *db;
 15    char *zErrMsg = 0;
 16    int rc;
 17  
 18    if( argc!=3 ){
 19      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s DATABASE SQL-STATEMENT\n", argv[0]);
 20      return(1);
 21    }
 22    rc = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db);
 23    if( rc ){
 24      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
 25      sqlite3_close(db);
 26      return(1);
 27    }
 28    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, argv[2], callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
 29    if( rc!=SQLITE_OK ){
 30      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
 31      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
 32    }
 33    sqlite3_close(db);
 34    return 0;
 35  }
```